# Responsive Css Floating DIV not working properly on window resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create table like DIV with tiles and middle tile would be the double the size.
**Problem is when using Bootstrap Responsive css , div floats around in different shapes and original table structure is not preserved, when you reszie the window. i want the double size tile always in the middle.**

http://jsfiddle.net/justinhomes/Y2jns/
i had tried using

```
<table>
<tr> <td>
```

but that is not helping as it stays fixed while browsing on mobile. i wanted something that can resize based on window size. how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If the table is too big and word wrap is still not good you may have to do a media query and lose a   Column